# Arrange Queries in single query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with columns Employee, Department and Salary.

- Column 1: Department.
- Column 2: No of People whose salary is in range (0 to 5000)
- Column 3: No of People whose Salary is in range (5000 to 10000)
- Column 4: No of People whose Salary is in range (10000 to 15000)
- Column 5,6,7: Sum of Salary also, with range used in columns 2,3,4.

How to arrange in single query with multiple salary conditions?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking here. Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will; help us help you.

Comment: No of people in Salary Range with total of Salary of that no of people.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    department,
    sum(case when                    salary <= 5000  then 1 else 0 end) count_salary_500,
    sum(case when salary > 5000  and salary <= 10000 then 1 else 0 end) count_salary_501_1000,
    sum(case when salary > 10000 and salary <= 15000 then 1 else 0 end) count_salary_10001_15000,
    sum(case when salary                    <= 5000  then salary end) sum_salary_500,
    sum(case when salary > 5000  and salary <= 10000 then salary end) sum_salary_501_1000,
    sum(case when salary > 10000 and salary <= 15000 then salary end) sum_salary_10001_15000
from mytable
group by department
```